# Laravel activitylog, erro na implementação

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou seguindo a documentação do site: https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v2/basic-usage/logging-activity, porém não estou conseguindo implementar a opção abaixo:

**Setting a subject
You can specify on which object the activity is performed by using performedOn:**

```
activity()
   ->performedOn($someContentModel)
   ->log('edited');

$lastActivity = Activity::all()->last(); //returns the last logged activity

$lastActivity->subject; //returns the model that was passed to `performedOn`;
The performedOn-function has a shorter alias name: on
```

Quando eu tento passar os parâmetros no controller ele gera erro no `performedOn($someContentModel)`, gostaria de saber o que devo usar no lugar da variável $someContentModel.

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar o "retorno" de uma MODEL sua .. ex:

```
$someContentModel = User::first();
```

Comment: Deu certo, estava passando o parametro ::all() por isso não dava certo. Valeu amigo!

Comment: Sem querer abusar, mas você sabe como usa o -> Using the CausesActivity trait da documentação? Não estou conseguindo implementar ela, creio que serve para acompanhar o que cada usuário fez no sistema de log, seria bem útil.

Comment: Você chama l Trait dentro da sua MODEL ele da o exemplo aqui
https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-activitylog/v2/advanced-usage/logging-model-events#ignoring-attributes-from-logging